# Less formal way of saying "I reserve all rights"

Tags: demand-letter

When legal personnel write letters on behalf of their clients, they often include a sentence saying "Our client reserves all rights."

There are good reasons for doing so. However, if a legally untrained person writes "I reserve all rights" (on his own behalf), it sounds like formal legalese, and may end up aggravating the other side's emotions.

Is there a way of rephrasing the sentence that preserves the meaning while not letting the situation get too emotionally charged?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of rephrasing the sentence that preserves the meaning while not letting the situation get too emotionally charged?

In most contexts a phrase like "*Our client reserves all rights*" is verbose because the person who "reserves all rights" obviously would not issue a demand letter with the intent to waive the rights he is actually pursuing via that letter.

That being said, an alternative wording is that "*xyz shall not be construed as the person's waiver of his rights*". A comparison of the emotional impact of each wording is unclear and too subjective, though, since  "*I reserve all rights*" in and of itself does not really sound intimidating, aggressive, or emotionally charged in the first place.